# Can a crossover cable be used as a patch cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, patch, crossover

Can I connect a Netgear DGND3300 10/100 modem/router, via a *crossover cable*, to **either** a Gigabyte M61PME-S2 containing an nForce 10/100 chip **or** an Asrock P67 Extreme4 with Gigabit Ethernet, with the crossover cable working as a patch cable?

I know that with newer chips, auto mdix will kick in and patch cables can be used as crossovers. But I'm not sure of the other way around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Auto MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto-MDIX) means that the NIC will detect whether the cable is crossover or straight through and communicate accordingly.

You are fine if *either* device does the detection.

Comment: Right, so it'll work even if the crossover cable is plugged into a wall socket, which attaches to a patch cable connected to the router? And it won't fry anything? Cheers :)

Comment: Well, I tried it and hey presto, it works (at least with the GBE PC).